# How to deploy scikit-learn classifier model into ANN written in another language

Tags: c#, python, scikit-learn, neural-network, classification

I have a scikit-learn classifier:

```
MLPClassifier(activation='relu', alpha=0.0001, batch_size='auto', beta_1=0.9,
   beta_2=0.999, early_stopping=False, epsilon=1e-08,
   hidden_layer_sizes=(13, 13, 13), learning_rate='constant',
   learning_rate_init=0.001, max_iter=500, momentum=0.9,
   nesterovs_momentum=True, power_t=0.5, random_state=None,
   shuffle=True, solver='adam', tol=0.0001, validation_fraction=0.1,
   verbose=False, warm_start=False)
```

for which I have dumped the coefficients and bias weights:

```
print( mlp.coefs_ )
print( mlp.intercepts_ )
```

I need to deploy this into another environment and have built a structurally-matching ANN [63x14x14x14x1] in C# (loading up all the coefficients), but running a simple forward propagation does not give me any useful results.  Specifically, I expected a binary classifier and values [0,1) but instead have values in the 150 +/- 50 range.

Are there some internal functions (beyond the activation function) at each node between the sum of the inputs and the output that are implied in the classifier?  Is there any specific documentation that would/should have told me this?  Or am I missing something else entirely?